# Why does GitHub allow a branch with commits ahead & behind but contains no changes to be merged?

Tags: git, github, git-diff

A branch was merged in recently that contained a 3-line fix. The following day a branch was pull request was submitted that contained 2 lines of the 3-line fix. It was several commits behind, behind the original merged branch. The tree would look something like...

```
A1--A2--A3-------B3--C4
     \   \      /   /
      \   A3--B3   /
       \          /
        A2------C3
```

So B3 would contain the 3-line fix and C3 would contain 2 lines of it. When I go to inspect C4, it shows the diff for the commit even though there technically is none. In fact, when doing an interactive rebase, the rebase will stop and say it's an empty commit.

I am aware that git lets you merge empty commits but what I'm confused about is:

1. Why GitHub lets you merge (and to a certain extent, git) when it usually doesn't let you when there are no changes. I'm guessing it's related to the commits ahead/behind issue but just curious what is the underlying cause
2. Why does git show the diff for commits that have made no diff (sort'a pun intended)?

Comment: How are you viewing commit `C4`? (Specifically, are you using `git show`, or some other command, or some GUI, or what?)

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

Merges affect the *commit graph* and therefore by definition must always be allowed.  Some command-line commands that request merges can be done as a non-merge *fast-forward* operation, but the GitHub clicky buttons force a true merge for these cases.

#### Long

You have not answered my comment question, so I have to be a little vague or verbose in at least one part here.  Also, I realize now that your diagram has `A2`, `A3`, and `B3` in it twice, which means your diagram is wrong and we should have, e.g.:

```
A1--A2--A3-------B5--C4
     \   \      /   /
      \   B3--B4   /
       \          /
        C2------C3
```

or perhaps:

```
A1--A2--A3-------B4--C4
     \   \      /   /
      \   ----B3   /
       \          /
        --------C3
```

Last, before I get started, labeling these things as sequences of `An`, `Bn`, and `Cn`s is not really useful from a Git point of view, as it is irrelevant which branch(es) contain commits when it comes to looking at and merging commits.  What matters is the commits themselves and their parent/child relationships—branch names are merely for humans here. :-)  So let me re-draw this as:

```
...--A--B--C------H--I   <-- branchname
         \  \    /  /
          \  D--E  /
           \      /
            F----G
```

where `H` and `I` are merge commits.  (To *make* `H`, someone had to run:

```
git checkout branchname
```

when `branchname` pointed to `C` and then:

```
git merge --no-ff <identifier-selecting-E>
```

or something equivalent.  The `--no-ff` forces this to be a real merge rather than a fast-forward non-merge "merge".  Note that the GitHub "merge" button does this, i.e., uses `--no-ff`.)

> When I go to inspect [the final merge commit now called `I` in my diagram –ed.], it shows the diff for the commit even though there technically is none ...

This is where things get interesting.  As you should already know by now, each commit is a complete snapshot of all its files—commits *do not* contain differences from previous commits, they just contain the snapshot of files.

When we have an ordinary non-merge commit, such as `E`, that commit has *one* parent commit, so Git can easily show commit `E` by extracting the snapshot of its parent commit `D`, then extracting the snapshot for `E` itself, and comparing the two.  For every file that is different in those two snapshots, Git attempts to produce a minimal edit sequence that would change `D` into `E`.

If you run `git commit` and your index—the area from which Git builds new commits—matches the current commit, Git generally just tells you "nothing to commit" and refuses to make a commit.  Adding `--allow-empty` tells Git: *make the new snapshot even though it's identical to the current snapshot.*  It's not that the *snapshot itself* is empty, it's that the *changes from the previous commit* will be empty.  Hence there's no particular reason to bother making the new snapshot.

Merge commits are different.  In one way, they *are* just like ordinary commits: they hold a snapshot.  The difference is that they have *two* or more<sup>1</sup> parents, each of which *also* holds a snapshot.  This means that it's difficult to show the difference between the two snapshots, when there are at least three snapshots involved.

Some commands, such as `git log`, default to *not bothering*.  That is, they see that the commit they are displaying is a merge commit, and they just don't bother extracting any of the parents and computing diffs.

The `git show` command does something extra-clever by default, though: it extracts *all* the parents' snapshots, and the child merge commit's, and then compares each file in the child against *all* the parents' versions of that same file.  It then throws out any file that exactly matches *any* parent variant, and only for some file that's different from *both* parents, shows what Git calls a *combined diff*.  The combined diff output format is documented in [several Git manual pages including that for `git diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_combined_diff_format).

Adding the `-m` flag to these commands tells Git to *split* the merge into several virtual commits, one for each parent.  That is, instead of showing a combined diff for `I` vs both `H` *and* `G`, Git will show one diff of `H`-vs-`I`, and then a second diff of `G`-vs-`I`.  These diffs contain more information: for instance, if file `README.txt` is the same in `H`-vs-`I`, while `foo.txt` is different, you'll see `foo.txt`.  If `README.txt` differs in `G`-vs-`I` while `foo.txt` is the same, you'll see `README.txt`.  But if you get a combined diff, Git tosses out *both* `README.txt` (`H`'s matches `I`'s) *and* `foo.txt` (`G`'s matches `I`'s) so you won't see either file at all.

Now, even if all files exactly matched in *both* input commits—i.e., if the snapshots in `H` and `G` exactly matched—Git would still make the merge commit, because the merge commit `I` itself, with its two parent hash IDs pointing back to both `H` and `G`, is what records the fact that there *was* a merge.  This sets up the new *merge base* for future merges.  Git computes the merge base for a later `git merge` operation using the graph, so we need the graph node that joins these two nodes.  That's not the case in your example, but it's worth noting.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git calls a more-than-two-parents merge an *octopus merge*.  They don't do anything you cannot achieve with the more obvious pairwise merges, though.  Some other VCSes support only pairwise merging.

---

> In fact, when doing an interactive rebase, the rebase will stop and say [the merge is] an empty commit.

Rebase works by copying commits.  This requires turning each commit into a change-set, diffing the commit against its parent.  Merges by definition have at least two parents and therefore *cannot* be copied this way.<sup>2</sup>  Rebase's solution to this dilemma is that it *deletes* merge commits entirely.  However:

> ... So [`E`] would contain the 3-line fix and [`G`] would contain 2 lines of it.

Let's draw in a second branch name, pointing to `G`, to use for rebasing, without making merge commit `I` at all:

```
...--A--B--C------H   <-- branchname
         \  \    /
          \  D--E
           \
            F----G   <-- feature
```

We can run `git checkout feature` and then `git rebase branchname` (with or without `--interactive`).  Git will enumerate the commits reachable from `feature` that are not reachable from `branchname`, by starting at `G` and working backwards, and starting at `H` and working backwards.  These two "work backwards" steps come together at commit `B` so `B` is *not* copied, nor is any earlier commit.  That leaves commits `F` and `G` to be copied, in that order.

The copy of `F` probably just works, giving:

```
...--A--B--C------H   <-- branchname
         \  \    / \
          \  D--E   F'  <-- HEAD
           \
            F----G   <-- feature
```

(note that rebase works with a detached `HEAD`, pointing directly to some commit).

Now Git is ready to copy the change in `G`, which is to change two of those three lines that are already changed, leaving one alone.  Git sees that this is futile—those two lines are already changed—and, depending on context, either declares a merge conflict (so that you have to clean everything up and decide which is the correct final version), or just decides that there's nothing to change.  If Git does stop with a merge conflict, you fix it up, going with the three-lines-changed version from commit `F'`.  You run `git rebase --continue` to make it keep going, and at this point, Git says that there's nothing to commit.  You have a choice now: commit with `--allow-empty`, so as to retain the commit message and a separate snapshot (that matches its parent), or drop the commit entirely using `git rebase --skip`.

Assuming you do the latter, Git finishes the rebase by moving the name (`feature`) to point to the last commit it copied, and setting `ORIG_HEAD` to remember where `feature` used to point:

```
...--A--B--C------H   <-- branchname
         \  \    / \
          \  D--E   F'  <-- feature (HEAD)
           \
            F----G   <-- ORIG_HEAD
```

and it's all done.

---

<sup>2</sup>`git rebase -i` has an additional flag, `--preserve` or `-p`, that claims to preserve merges.  This is not true: it actually *re-performs* merges.  That is, it copies enough commits to set up the conditions for a merge, then it runs `git merge` to make a new merge.  If you resolved conflicts before, you are likely to have to do it again.  Even if you did not have to resolve conflicts before, you may have to at this point.  If you made the earlier merge with `git merge --no-commit` followed by editing the contents followed by `git merge --continue` or `git commit` to produce a so-called *evil merge*, Git has no idea that you did this, and makes a new non-evil merge that drops all your sneakiness.  If that sneakiness was actually a *good* thing, despite the term *evil merge*, you will have lost it.